# How to get the row number when using alias in orderby

Tags: sql, postgresql-10

I have a query. I use an alias in order by when using row_number and I got

> [42703] ERROR: column "total_comments" does not exist error Position: 335

How can I fix this?

```
 select
      cr_seller_history_id,
      c.created_at,
      company_name,
      business_name,
      brand,
      kep_mail,
      address,
      phone,
      mail,
      slug,
      name,
      point,
      contact_positive,
      contact_negative,
      product_number,
      (product_positive + product_negative) as total_comments,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY total_comments) as rank
    from cr_companies a
      INNER JOIN cr_sellers b ON a.cr_company_id = b.cr_company_id
      INNER JOIN cr_seller_histories c ON b.cr_seller_id = c.cr_seller_id
      WHERE DATE(c.created_at) = DATE 'yesterday'
    ORDER BY total_comments DESC NULLS LAST
```

Comment: total_comments is an alias that's the problem I suppose
Position: 335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY total_comments) as rank
```

you can't use alias like this - `order by` accepts alias in select, not in window function:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
>   ORDER BY and GROUP BY clauses, but not in the WHERE or HAVING clauses;
>   there you must write out the expression instead.

instead try:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (product_positive + product_negative)) as rank
```

or use subquery - then alias can be used in window function

Comment: I have to find a solution to find the number of the row. I cannot write the total_comments value to a field all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are a subquery, CTE, or a lateral join.  So, you can write:

```
select . . . 
      v.total_comments,
      row_number() over (order by v.total_comments) as rank
from cr_companies c join
     cr_sellers s
     on c.cr_company_id = s.cr_company_id join
     cr_seller_histories sh
     on s.cr_seller_id = sh.cr_seller_id, lateral
     (values (product_positive + product_negative)) v(total_comments)
where DATE(c.created_at) = date 'yesterday'
order by v.total_comments desc nulls last;
```

Notice that I also changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names.  This is a best practice and makes it much easier to write, read, and modify queries.

Comment: Honestly I solved my problem with subquery. However, yours seems to be more professional.